# Google maps into website based on user info

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So i checked out all the relating posts.  I was wondering, which i have yet to be able to find with about 20 google searches and about 45 website visits, if it is possible, based on users information that i could load a google map to display the users desired location.

Your probably asking, "Give me more details, that could mean anything!"

Your right, it could.  So say i have a user that gives me (i got it from the database)
    
        `var stuffIGotFromMyWebServerWithPHPandMySQL = {

        myComment: "Hey Everyone, party at my place!",

            country: "US",

            state: "MT",

            city: "Bozeman",

            address: "Emerson Cultural Center"

        };`

Now that i have the information of what city/state/country the event is in, and the name of a place, The Emerson is a real place in bozeman that google maps will recognize, is there a way to load a map with a marker at that location?  I have the latitude/longitude for bozeman, MT, but i do not have such information about the Emerson.  Is there a way i could provide the just the words, and have it bring up the place with a marker, on a static, no user interaction allowed map?

and i would probably want to load it through js

Thanks,

Michael B Paulson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
  var marker;

  function initialize() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode(
      {
        'address': 'Emerson Cultural Center, Bozeman, MT'
      },
      function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          }
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:map,
            draggable:false,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;width:300px"></div>
```

try this code and see if helps, you can use the Geocoder fro the google maps api to convert text to latlang.

you can see the following example from the documentation here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple.html

Comment: @Israhack  Thanks bud.  I'll have time to test this either tonight or tomorrow.  I am now knee deep in getting google calendar stuff to work.  Only thing not working is the silly dates.  They do a funny format, so i am going to see if just the php time() works :)  Thanks.  Ill update this thread tomorrow morning.

Comment: Sorry, i had such a time trying to figure out how to make google buzz buttons be updated with ajax material (Which turns out i could not figure it out, instead wasted like 5 hours on it).

Comment: Hey @Israhack, question.  I am going to do some looking, but do you know if there is a limited amount of times i am allowed to call that google.geocode function?

Comment: So it turns out that i am limited to 2500 maps request per day.  I would blow through fairly quick.  So i will probably have to stick with static images because of that limit (I do not have the money to afford the premium map API).  But this works.  So you get the correct answer award :)